# Does the REST API Message method support data extension attributes

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, dataextensions, send-email

I have a use case for a transactional message where the web service would like to push information from a purchase order as data attributes not associated to the subscriber profile at time of send (p/n, part description, image url, etc.)

I know the SOAP method supports this by allowing you to create a trigger data extension  associated to the triggerSend, but I see 'profile' mentioned in all the REST documentation. Any insight would be helpful as I'm sure this approach isn't uncommon.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This works with REST as well. In this example I have a field 'token' in a Sendable Data Extension associated to the Triggered Send...'token' is not a Profile Attribute in the system. Node sample below using the fuel npm.

```
          var tsdOpts = {
              "From": {
                  "Address": "test@domain.com",
                  "Name": "Test Name"
              },
              "To": {
                  "Address": "rob@rob.com",
                  "SubscriberKey": "rob@rob.com",
                  "ContactAttributes": {
                      "SubscriberAttributes": {
                          "token": "DH^&XCUDKD*!SD"
                      }
                  }
              }
          };

          //load fuel
          var fuel = require('fuel').configure({
              authUrl: 'https://auth.exacttargetapis.com/v1/requestToken',
              clientId: 'xxx',
              clientSecret: 'xxx'
          });

          //cue tsd
          fuel({
              url: 'https://www.exacttargetapis.com/messaging/v1/messageDefinitionSends/key:xxxx/send',
              method: 'post',
              body: tsdOpts
          }, function (err, response, body) {
              done(err, 'done');
          });
        }
```